# How can I view what is taking up storage space by my react native app?

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

On my iphone if I go to Settings>iPhone storage>click my app>
It says documents & data 1.33 GB

EDIT: I've managed to view files by going to Xcode >Windows>Devices>Select Phone>Click cog icon>View Container

[image]

But is there any way to view file size?